# Magento Order emails and the core_email_queue table

Tags: email, magento-1.9.2.0

A quick question regarding this. I'm running Magento 1.9.2.0

Does the core_email_queue table contents get truncated after each cron or does it just fill up? Or does it clear every 24 hours or anything like that?

I've my cron set to 5 mins and appear to potentially have the a lot of emails being sporadicly sent, and clients customers saying they haven't received, though admittedly every test I've performed has went through fine. The processed_at column is being populated etc with relevant times.

I've not sure if mines just stuck? Whats the best way to clear it if it is and what other tables should I do at the same time, is it best to truncate?.

Thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 2):

Ok it appears that yes, the core_queue_table and the core_email_queue_recipients tables get cleared, in what I assume to be the usual housekeeping that the cron job performs.

I think the problem that I was facing lies either with the deliverability of the email and / or a over zealous email server at the recipients end.